# How to add Spinner using onCreateView

Tags: android, spinner

I have Sliding Menu using fragments and I want to add a Spinner and a Button in `fragment_one` but I don't know what to use, since I'm new in android I'm trying with this code but everytime I click on `fragment_one` the app closes. Hope someone can help me with my problem for spinner and button.

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one,container, false);

        spinner1=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        btnSearch=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

        spinner1.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
        spinner2.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

        return view;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "I want to add a Spinner and a Button in fragment_one"?

Your layout "fragment_one" must already have yours views. If not, you can't find it with "findViewById".

Can you post the exception with the stacktrace?

Comment: everytime i run the app and click an item from ListView to open fragment_one my project app close